# Test Resolver in AWS AppSync w/ API Key?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, vtl

Currently AWS AppSync provides an option to add test context to test your resolver to make sure everything is correct. However, because I am using API Key for authentication, I'm not sure of a way to set this in the request mapping template so that the test context can run and I can test the validity of my API (especially since this is the only auth that doesn't have an identity section in the test context)? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in the fact that API Key Authorization mode does not populate the identity, even when you are calling your API from a client.

However, you can still add an identity object in your test context. To do this, you need to:

1. Get the authorization mode you will be using in the future (IAM, Cognito, OIDC).
2. Find the fields that authorization mode provides in the ctx.identity. You can find that here: [Resolver Context Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html#aws-appsync-resolver-context-reference-identity)
3. Add those fields to your test context. For example, IAM test context might look like this:

   {
       "identity": {
           "accountId": "my aws account",
           "cognitoIdentityPoolId": "string",
           "cognitoIdentityId": "string",
           "sourceIp": ["string"],
           "username": "string",
           "userArn": "string"
       },
       "arguments": {},
       "source": {
           "lambda": "Hello, world!",
           "testCtx": "Hello, world!"
       },
       "result": "Hello, world!"
   }

The request mapping template could look like this:

```
{
    "account: "$ctx.identity.accountId"
}
```

and the evaluated request mapping template would look like this when your test context is run:

```
{
    "account: "my aws account"
}
```

Note: You may also just want to switch your API to the authorization mode you plan on using, and then try queries as a logged-in user.

Comment: thank you for this advice! However, even when I change the authorization mode, when I run the test, the response mapping template comes up null? And I supposed to run a query in order to get the test context to appear?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to give an answer to the response mapping template returning null without seeing your response mapping template. There is a test button on the resolver page which tests the resolver in your web browser using the test context you created. If you run a query from the console's query page, your request will go the AppSync service, the context will get populated by the service, and you will get a response after your resolver runs on the service.